# Mostrar en cosola datos de un array en Java

Tags: java, array, consola

Quiero extraer y mostrar en consola los datos de una persona en un array en Java que contenga varios datos repetidos como estos: dni "Nombre Compuesto", "Apellidos" y fecha. Y que muestre en una linea el dni, en otra linea el nombre compuesto en mayúsculas y un espacio en blanco entre las palabras, otra linea con los apellidos en mayúsculas y un espacio en blanco separándolos y otra con la fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd.

Un ejemplo a partir de esto, que no sé si correcto:

```
 double[][] matriz={{22456789L, "Jose Tomas", "Gonzalez Alcantara", 22/08/1972},{22456789L, "Luis jose", "Alcantara Perez", 02/02/1932}};
```

Comment: La Línea que colocas como ejemplo es incorrecta. Recomendaría usar Clases para este propósito , e imprimir los objetos mediante el método `toString();` que todas las clases deben tener (Ahí le das el formato deseado) teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de @Andres Sanchez

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo completo con código, porfavor?.

Comment: Ya proporcione un ejemplo, Espero pueda ayudarle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La Línea Propuesta como ejemplo está mal pensada lo más cerca que podría ser así sería que sea un Arreglo de `String`

```
String[][] personas = new String[][]
    { {"12345678","Nombre1 Apellido1","2016/10/12"}, 
      {"99999999","Nombre2 Apellido2","2015/10/12"}
    };
```

Para tal tarea propongo usar `clases` con los atributos respectivos que plantea detallo un ejemplo básico, para tratar y crear Objetos

```
public class Person {

  /* Atributos */
  private String dni;
  private String nombre;
  private String apellido;
  private String fecha;

  /* Contructores */
  public Person() {
  }

  public Person(String dni, String nombre, String apellido, String fecha) {
      this.dni = dni;
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.apellido = apellido;
      this.fecha = fecha;
  }

  /* Aquí irían sus getter y setters */

  /* Método toString */
   public String toString() {
    /* \n para el salto de línea y toUpperCase() para mostrar en mayúsculas */
    return "DNI : " +dni +"\n"+
            "Nombre : "+ nombre.toUpperCase() +"\n"+
            "Apellido : "+ apellido.toUpperCase() +"\n"+
            "Fecha  : " +fecha+"\n";
   }
```

En su clase Principal , debería crear un `arreglo` de Objetos de tipo `Person` y la impresión sería mediante un `for` de objetos llamando al método `toString();`

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Person[] personas = new Person[2]; /* Arreglo de Objetos*/
   /* Llamo al Constructor con Parametros */
  personas[0]= new Person("12345678", "nombre1", "apellido1", "2014/12/12");
  personas[1]= new Person("98765432", "nombre2", "apellido2", "2014/02/06");

    for (Person persona : personas) {
        /* LLamamos al Método toString(); de la clase Person*/
        System.out.println(persona.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir nueva linea usas el carácter de escape \n, y para imprimir con espacio pues simplemente haces una concatenación de un carácter vació.

> System.out.println(array[pos] + " " + array[pos] + "\n");

No olvides para recorrer el array un ciclo.

Comment: Puedes escribir un ejemplo con un array de prueba. Osea el ejemplo completo.

Comment: Yo creo que el ejemplo completo no es necesario dado que el que hizo la pregunta no dio ningún ejemplo (ni siquiera incompleto)

Comment: He editado la pregunata, ahoara tiene un ejemplo